# ggsave does not save all the elements to pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code generates a plot with ggplot and grid.arrange. When I save in pdf format, top and bottom page annotations are lost

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)


plots <- lapply(unique(mtcars$cyl), function(cyl) {
    data <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl == cyl)
    ggplot(data, aes(x=mpg, y=hp))+
        geom_point(color = "blue")+
        facet_wrap(.~carb)}) %>% 
    do.call(grid.arrange, .)
do.call(grid.arrange, c(plots,list(top="top", bottom="bottom")) )
ggsave(file="C:\\temp\\plot.pdf", plots, width = 21, height = 29.7, units = "cm", dpi = 300)
```

Comment: I think the issue is that you pass `plots` to `ggsave()`, not the output of `do.call()`.

Comment: problem solved! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `plots` is passed to `ggsave()`, but not the actually desired plot, namely, the output of `do.call()`. This should work instead:

```
tmp1 <- do.call(grid.arrange, c(plots, list(top = "top", bottom = "bottom")))
ggsave(file = "C:\\temp\\plot.pdf", plot = tmp1)
```